# Error in implementation of Web Service in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat8

When I am creating a web service in eclipse with tomcat as the server, I am getting this error:

> IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.ac.open.t320.Hello cannot be found by org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis.consumption.core_1.0.600.v201910301957.

This is my code-

```
package uk.ac.open.t320;

public class Hello {
    public String helloName(String name)
    {
        return "Hello there"+ name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can check if the name of file in which you are writing code is Hello.java

Comment: Yes, the file is Hello.java.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this question:[Error in generating WSDL from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166063/error-in-generating-wsdl-from-java)

Right click uk.ac.open.t320 -> Export->Jar file->export to /WEB-INF/lib